# NetBeans settings for GCC

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans, makefile, mingw

When I click on project properties I can set `Warning level` (`More Warnings`) and `Command Line -> Additional Options` (`-std=c99`). But I want that all my C project have that kind of options by default without manually setting them everytime I create new project.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: just a note: while `XP1` is totally correct, in simple cases you may make do with just [CFLAGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFLAGS)

Answer (score 5):

For each project, the configuration properties are saved in the `\nbproject\configurations.xml` (`%UserProfile%\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjectName\nbproject\configurations.xml`) file.

You could share the `configurations.xml` file between projects so that you won't have to change and apply every setting.

---

You could create a default project and configure it however you like. Instead of creating a new project, you could copy it, and name it something else.

---

If you want the toolchain properties to apply to every project, you will need to manually modify your toolchain definition or create a new one.

- Generate shadow copies of the tool collection descriptors:

  - NetBeans > File > Exit.
  - Gain write access to modify `%ProgramFiles%\NetBeans x\etc\netbeans.conf`:

    - Start > Run > `%ProgramFiles%\NetBeans x\`.
    - Right click on the `etc` folder > Properties > Security > Edit... > Under "Group and user names", select the "Users" group > Under "Permissions for Users", for "Full control", enable "Allow" > OK > OK.
  - Open `%ProgramFiles%\NetBeans x\etc\netbeans.conf` in a text editor that can handle the newlines.

    - On the line starting with `netbeans_default_options`, add `-J-Dcnd.toolchain.personality.create_shadow=true` to the string of values.

      - For example, the line may now look like:

        `netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dcnd.toolchain.personality.create_shadow=true"`
    - Save the file.
    - If you had imported settings from an older profile that had generated shadow copies previously to a 7.2+ profile, then you must open the `toolchain.properties` file in `%Appdata%\NetBeans\x\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\cnd\`. In `toolchain.properties`, remove the line `toolchain_shadow=true`, and save.

      - If you do not do this step after upgrading and importing the NetBeans profile, NetBeans may not generate the shadow copies. Also, you may not be able to use any build tools, and you may get a "No compiler sets were found in the directory ..." error when you try to configure the C/C++ build tools.
    - Open and then close NetBeans.
    - On the line starting with `netbeans_default_options`, remove `-J-Dcnd.toolchain.personality.create_shadow=true` from the string of values. In other words, undo the edit to restore the file back to its original state.
    - Save the file.
- Modify or create the toolchain definition:

  - Start > Run > `%Appdata%\NetBeans\x\config\CND\ToolChain\` (7.2+) or `%UserProfile%\.netbeans\x\config\CND\ToolChain\` (7.1.2-).
  - Locate the corresponding XML file for your toolchain.

    - For example, the MinGW toolchain definition file is `MinGW.xml`.
  - Open the XML file in a text editor that can handle the newlines.
  - Within the `c` element, there is a `development_mode` element containing the different development mode option elements. You can modify the flags for a particular development mode by modifying the `flags` attribute.

    - For example, when you add the `-std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0` flags, the attributes may look like this:

      ```
      <development_mode>
          <fast_build flags="-std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0"/>
          <debug default="true" flags="-std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g"/>
          <performance_debug flags="-std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g -O"/>
          <test_coverage flags="-std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g"/>
          <diagnosable_release flags="-std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g -O2"/>
          <release flags="-std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -O2"/>
          <performance_release flags="-std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -O3"/>
      </development_mode>
      ```
  - Within the `cpp` element, there is a `development_mode` element containing the different development mode option elements. You can modify the flags for a particular development mode by modifying the `flags` attribute.

    - For example, when you add the `-std=c++11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0` flags, the attributes may look like this:

      ```
      <development_mode>
          <fast_build flags="-std=c++11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0"/>
          <debug default="true" flags="-std=c++11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g"/>
          <performance_debug flags="-std=c++11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g -O"/>
          <test_coverage flags="-std=c++11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g"/>
          <diagnosable_release flags="-std=c++11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g -O2"/>
          <release flags="-std=c++11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -O2"/>
          <performance_release flags="-std=c++11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -O3"/>
      </development_mode>
      ```
  - Save the file.

For finding the `netbeans.conf` configuration file on different platforms, see:

- How do I make my custom startup parameters permanent?

  http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf

For finding the user directories on different platforms, see:

- What is a *userdir* and where can I find it?
  What is a *cachedir* and where can I find it?

  http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

For information on tool collection descriptors, see:

- Using the C/C++ Tool Collection Descriptor - NetBeans IDE 6.9 Tutorial:

  http://netbeans.org/kb/69/cnd/toolchain.html

Comment: FWIW, a general IDE-agnostic solution I've used is an old trick - either use the [CFLAGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFLAGS), or (mostly toolchain-independent) simply create a `.exe` that calls `system` with the compiler/linker as first param, additional ones from a config file, and finally adding all the actual `argv` parameters. Either create a brand new dir with redirectors only or rename all the old `.exe`'s to something else.

Answer (score 1):

First download and install Code::Blocks IDE from [Code::Blocks IDE Downlowd](http://space.dl.sourceforge.net/project/codeblocks/Binaries/10.05/Windows/codeblocks-10.05mingw-setup.exe) and [MSYS 1.0.11](http://space.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/MSYS/BaseSystem/msys-core/msys-1.0.11/MSYS-1.0.11.exe)

All setting will automatically configured, but you have to select "make" command from

```
C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. @gameboy is talking about the default project properties, not the build tools.

Answer (score 0):

Using netBeans 8.1 under Windows 7 Professional with MinGW (gcc), I found the file

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\cnd***toolchain.properties***,

but I can't find the folder

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\CND

(so I can't find C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\CND\ToolChain)

I found the folder

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\cnd

but there's no ***MinGW.xml*** file there. I find this ***MinGW.xml*** file nowhere on the hard disk drive where NetBeans (and MinGW) are installed.