# Setting Default NetBeans Options (-std=c99, -Wall) for C programs

Tags: c, netbeans, compilation, default, compiler-options

I have **NetBeans 6.9** installed and working fine on Ubuntu Linux 11.10. My goal is to set **compiler options** like `-Wall` and `-std=c99` to be used by default. Currently, I have to right click on my project -> Properties -> C Compiler -> Warning Level to "**More Warnings**" and add `-std=c99` to **Additional Options**. This is obviously a pain when creating many projects, and **I'm sure there is a way to make all of this the default**.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114042/netbeans-settings-for-gcc) which relates closely to my question. However, the only answer involves installing Code::Blocks and MSYS 1.0.11, which doesn't make much sense to me. I don't see how installing another IDE will help me, and MSYS seems unnecessary, as I am already using Linux.

I have tried every reasonable search term I can imagine, and am very surprised how little info I have turned up. It seems like most everyone who uses NetBeans should have to change this type of thing at some point. Terms I'm searching for: *'NetBeans -std=c99 default'*,  *'NetBeans set default compile options'*, *'how to make NetBeans use c99 by default'* and *'Code::Blocks settings into NetBeans'*.

Comment: I'm still not aware of an answer to this question, and I would still love to know if anyone has any info, btw. This question is very much still open.

Comment: Please don't use link shorteners. Using link shorteners will prevent Stack Overflow from linking to related questions in the sidebar.

Comment: What link shorteners? If any existed, you've already removed them or I'm somehow missing them.

Comment: just a note: while `XP1` is totally correct, in simple cases you may make do with just [CFLAGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFLAGS)

Answer (score 5):

Here are some different things that you can do:

1. Copy and share the configuration files between projects, so you won't have to set every setting.
2. Create a default project, and configure however you like it. When you want to create a new project, just copy the default project and rename it to something else.
3. Modify your toolchain properties.

For details, see here:

[NetBeans settings for GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114042/netbeans-settings-for-gcc/11643274#11643274)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Project Template Module. I was aware this is possible but didn't try it before, and this link is explaining how to do it;
https://blogs.oracle.com/seapegasus/entry/tip_create_your_own_project

(First you need NetBeans with platform SDK, not just C/C++ Bundle.)

I followed steps;

- Open/Create your project with settings you want to use.
- Create a NetBeans module project, choose a Code Base Name, i gave my.templates.ctemplate1
- Add "Module Development > Project Template" to the module project. Choose your C project in "Select Project" step.
- At next step select the Category as C/C++ and give a name for template i used MyCTemplate1.
- Right click on module project and select "Create NBM", it will create my-templates-ctemplate1.nbm in the build folder of the module project.
- Tools > Plugins > Downloaded , click "Add Plugin" and point to the nbm file in the build folder. Select install, it will give warnings because it's not signed.
- When you want to create a new C/C++ project you will see your template in the wizard which will have all the settings as your first C project has.

Enjoy other possibilities; files, folders in original project will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing your `netbeans.conf` file (for me, it's in `/usr/local/netbeans-7.0.1/etc/netbeans.conf`) and adding the options you need to the `netbeans_default_options` line?  From looking at my version of the file, you might need to prepend `-J` to the switches (hence `-Wall` would become `-J-Wall`.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried appending `-J-std=c99 -J-Wall` to the end of the `netbeans_default_options` line. With that style, NetBeans would not launch. I then removed the `-J` options, so that I had appended `-std=c99 -Wall`. NetBeans would then launch, but no options had changed. I could not compile a `for(int i = 0;;);` loop, for example. My guess is that netbeans.conf is for Java options. There are lots of references to JVM and Sun, and none to C things. Tomorrow, I will look around for a .conf file I can use to modify C default options. Thank you for putting me on a fresh track!

Comment: Sorry that didn't help you.  I assume that you've already seen the [Netbeans C/C++ Trail](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/cnd.html)?

Comment: I hadn't seen the trail, thanks for linking to it. I will have to explore it more later.

I found a page about [http://bit.ly/tqQxqP netbeans.conf]. It seems that only [http://bit.ly/tsEGRl](these) start up parameters can be passed to NetBeans, either by the command line or the global or local version of `netbeans.conf`. None of those seem helpful, for this particular problem.