# How to add a library include path for NetBeans and gcc on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc, netbeans

How to add a library include path for NetBeans and gcc on Windows?

Using:

- NetBeans 7.1.2
- MinGW (`mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe`)
- gcc 4.7.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For example, you want to add the directories in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include\` as the include paths.

First, set up code assistance:

- NetBeans > Tools > Options > C/C++ > Code Assistance

  - C Compiler > Include Directories:

    - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include\shared`
    - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include\other`
    - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include`
    - `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.0\include`
    - `C:\MinGW\include`
    - `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.0\include-fixed`
    - ...
  - C++ Compiler > Include Directories:

    - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include\shared`
    - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include\other`
    - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include`
    - `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.0\include\c++`
    - `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.0\include\c++\mingw32`
    - `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.0\include\c++\backward`
    - `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.0\include`
    - `C:\MinGW\include`
    - `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.0\include-fixed`
    - ...
  - OK.

The `C:\MinGW\...` directories are examples only. Do not actually add them. NetBeans should have detected and added the MinGW directories automatically. If not, try resetting the settings:

- NetBeans > Tools > Options > C/C++

  - Code Assistance

    - C Compiler > Reset Settings
    - C++ Compiler > Reset Settings
  - Build Tools

    - Restore Defaults

---

For instructions on automatic code assistance for existing sources, see:

- C/C++ Projects Quick Start Tutorial:

  http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/quickstart.html#makefileprojects
- How to Configure Code Assistance When Creating a Project from Existing Code:

  http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/configuring-code-assistance.html

---

Now, configure the project options:

- Right click on project > Properties

  - Configuration: <All Configurations>
  - Build

    - C Compiler

      - General

        - Include Directories:

          - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include\shared`
          - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include\other`
          - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include`
      - Compilation Line

        - Additional Options:

          - `-std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0`
    - C++ Compiler

      - General

        - Include Directories:

          - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include\shared`
          - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include\other`
          - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include`
      - Compilation Line

        - Additional Options:

          - `-std=c++11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0`
  - OK.

For adding command-line options by default for all projects, see:

- [NetBeans settings for GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114042/netbeans-settings-for-gcc/11643274#11643274)

Any spaces in the path should be automatically escaped. Any backward slashes should be replaced with forward slashes automatically.

For example, the "All options" textbox in "Additional Options" looks like this:

```
-std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g -I/C/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Example/1.0/include/shared -I/C/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Example/1.0/include/other -I/C/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Example/1.0/include
```

If this does not work, you may have to fix the path and add the includes manually in the additional options. For example, replace `/C/` with `C:/`.

```
-std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g -IC:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Example/1.0/include/shared -IC:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Example/1.0/include/other -IC:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Example/1.0/include
```

If you are using Cygwin `make` and if you try to clean or rebuild the project with colons in the command, you may get a `*** multiple target patterns.  Stop.` error message. According to the answers from [Multiple target patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614758/multiple-target-patterns/) and [Very simple application fails with "multiple target patterns" from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401976/very-simple-application-fails-with-multiple-target-patterns-from-eclipse/), "`make` sees the `:` in the path and thinks it is another target definition, hence the error."

The workaround is to delete the generated `build` and `dist` folders every time before you build your project. However, this can be annoying, so you could try MinGW MSYS `make` instead (not to be confused with MinGW `make`, which is [unsupported](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/cpp-setup-instructions.html#mingw)).

For MinGW and MSYS configuration instructions, see:

- Configuring the NetBeans IDE for C/C++/Fortran:

  http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/cpp-setup-instructions.html#mingw

For working with MinGW and Unicode, you should install the latest version of MinGW-w64. See:

- [wWinmain, Unicode, and Mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571250/wwinmain-unicode-and-mingw/11706847#11706847)

Comment: @JesseGood, how about `-std=c11`? So what other problems were you thinking about? Just because information exists somewhere else does not mean that it should not exist on Stack Overflow. I have also added more information about `make` issues that may not exist on the NetBeans website.

Comment: On code assistance, http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/quickstart.html and http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/configuring-code-assistance.html say that code assistance can be automatically configured from existing sources. However, if I create a new C project, type `#include <example.h>` at the top, and try to compile, it says `fatal error: example.h: No such file or directory`. It is not automatic. It does not magically know where `example.h` lives. I have to configure the location of `example.h` manually.

Comment: @JesseGood The `C:\MinGW\...` directories are only there to demonstrate what it looks like on my computer. Of course, it would be ridiculous to add them if they already exist. I have added your suggestions about the compiler flags.

Comment: The spaces in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Example\1.0\include` should be automatically escaped. As you can see from the "All options" textbox: `C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Example/1.0/include`. Some SDKs and headers install in `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: Last Comment: Looks a lot better (removed the downvote). Also, just using forward slashes `/` to begin with might be better to avoid problems. Hopefuly somebody finds this useful (I will delete my old comments as they just take up space).

Comment: This solution does not work. Still complains the included file does not exist.

Comment: How to include directories and all it's sub-directories at once?

Comment: There are no "C++ compiler" and "C compiler" sections under "Build" in Project -> Properties. Though under "Code Assistance" they are present. Using Netbeans IDE 18 with C++ plugin.