# C++ Compiler cannot find files without absolute path in Steinberg VST SDK files

Tags: c++, netbeans, sdk, vst

I'm trying to compile a simple program that's already been written included in the Steinberg VST SDK.

The issue I'm having is my compiler can't find the file unless it has an absolute path. For some reason, the code is written in such a way that my compiler can't find where the file needed it.

For example:

In the file vstcomponentbase.h, located in C:\Users\180945\Documents\Programs\vstsdk352_25_09_2012_build_16\VST3 SDK\public.sdk\source\vst\

There is this line:

```
#include "pluginterfaces/base/ipluginbase.h"
```

ipluginbase.h is located in C:\Users\180945\Documents\Programs\vstsdk352_25_09_2012_build_16\VST3 SDK\plugininterfaces\base

Unless I change the line to

```
#include "C:\Users\180945\Documents\Programs\vstsdk352_25_09_2012_build_16\VST3 SDK\pluginterfaces\base\ipluginbase.h"
```

it won't work.

I'm using NetBeans as my IDE. I'd like for the files to automatically find where the files are supposed to be. It should work, as I'm using Steinberg's VST SDK, which has demonstrations and other bits of code that are supposed to work as given. There would be too many things to edit in something that should already work.

Comment: `pluginterfaces` or `plugininterfaces`?

Comment: @Jamil, well, apparently not. Compare your two lines again. You claim that the one with `plugininterfaces` is the one that works...

Comment: @us2012 I apologize. I definitely typed it wrong. It should be `pluginterfaces` I just edited the question to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

How would the compiler know where you have hidden those include files :) ? You need to add `"C:\Users\180945\Documents\Programs\vstsdk352_25_09_2012_build_16\VST3 SDK"` to the search path for include files in your compiler options. For gcc, the relevant option is `-I`, but many IDEs have a way of setting the include path in the project settings. Consult your IDE's manual.

Comment: It says it's using g++. I tried adding `-I "C:\Users\180945\Documents\Programs\vstsdk352_25_09_2012_build_16\VST3 SDK"` to the g++ compiler options, but I achieved the same errors. I also tried following this tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621885/how-to-add-a-library-include-path-for-netbeans-and-gcc-on-windows for NetBeans and I still got the same errors.

Comment: Have you seen the comment by Peter Wood under your question?

Comment: Yes, I just replied. The code in the original SDK should be 100% correct.