# Netbeans C++ Application won't build

Tags: c++, netbeans

I recently installed the MiniGW compiler so that I can start learning C++. But when I go to create a new project and have it include main, I get two error messages from the start(after the project has been created) `Cannot Find Include File <cstdlib>` and `Unable to resolve identifier std` and when I try and 'Clean and Build' the project, the clean is successful and the build is not. I have done a google search and ran across this post [Netbeans 7.2 shows "Unable to resolve identifier" , although build is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913243/netbeans-7-2-shows-unable-to-resolve-identifier-although-build-is-successful) , but I'm not sure my problem is exactly the same since my project won't build (or maybe it is, I don't know), and I'm also not sure I understand the accepted answer. Can this be multiple problems or just one? I want to get this fixed so I can learn!

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: Zf
 *
 * Created on December 16, 2014, 1:50 PM
 */

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Lines 7 and 8 are where the error messages are.

Comment: Can you post the code that's not compiling?

Comment: Yeah, sorry bout that.

Comment: How are you compiling it, from the command line of from netbeans?

Comment: Netbeans, when I run the project, the build fails. I'll look into this other post you included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you `Tool Collection` set properly ?

for example 
`<cstdlib>` is found in `C:\minGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++`

[image]

Comment: I think that did it, thank you. One more thing though, although the errors went away, I now have a warning on the #include line. It says "There are unresolved includes inside <cstdlib>. What does this mean? Did I miss something? Sorry, this is all very new to me, installing ney beans for Java was a lot more simple then this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sounds like you need to tell the compiler where to find cstdlib. See this: [How to add a library include path for NetBeans and gcc on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621885/how-to-add-a-library-include-path-for-netbeans-and-gcc-on-windows)
2. Cstdlib contains C functions, they are not wrapped in a namespace. Remove the `using namespace std;` line